# trouble passing django variables to my template

Tags: python

my views.py file

```
    def NoticeView(request):
        notices=Notice.objects.all()
        context={'notices':notices}

        return render(request,'aider/notice.html',context)
```

my model

```
    class Notice(models.Model):
        headline=models.CharField(max_length=150)
        notice_text=models.TextField()
        publication_date=models.DateTimeField('date 
        published',default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Notice-detail',args=[str(self.id)])
```

my template

```
<div>
    <ul>
    {% for notices in notices %}
        <li>
            <div">
                <span><h5>{{ Notice.headline}}</h5></span>
                <p>{{Notice.notice_text}}</p>
                <p><span> Posted On {{Notice.publication_date}}</span></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The template shows a proper for loop iteration but is blank on where variables should be, i hope it my question makes sense...thanks

Answer (score -1):

`views.py` is correct. Look at your for loop in template file. Do not use `for notices in notices` as it wrong. Use different variable names.

```html
<div>
    <ul>
    {% for notice in notices %}
        <li>
            <div>
                <span><h5>{{ notice.headline }}</h5></span>
                <p>{{ notice.notice_text }}</p>
                <p><span> Posted On {{ notice.publication_date }}</span></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I used ***notice*** as item, not ***notices***. `for notices in notices` is wrong.

Comment: @Karthik `views.py` is still the same. It's correct.

Comment: @joy it looks correct. Do Notice models exist actually?

Comment: @stilManiac yes, I have the notice model, I just want forgot so show you... Let me show you